How to show IP of domain name in grafana?
I have a grafana with Prometheus, InfluxDB and MySQL plugins installed. I want to get the IP behind a domain name, for example, get 8.8.8.8 when querying dns.google.com, and show the result in a Grafana Dashboard.
I tried to :

Use MySQL query to get it. But everything I found is about the IP of the client
Use Grafana Agent that doesn't seems to be answering to my issue (cannot use it in grafan dashboard).
Find a Datasource or in plugin list, but I didn't find anything that can do this type of query.
Find a way to use PHP as the method gethostbyname($ip) do exactly what I want, but I can't execute PHP.

I don't want to save the result to have an history, I just want a real-time DNS manager to check for some DNS entry.
How can I do it? Like how to execute PHP in Grafana?

dns.google.com (A record) has also 8.8.4.4. DNS record may have many IPs, not just one, it can have also different types (AAAA for IPv6), so I wouldn't say that your approach is correct.

@JanGaraj I understand, but it's only example. The real DNS that I will check are only using IPv4, and have only one IP. So in my case, there is no problem

Not sure that this is the best idea to do DNS resolving directly in Grafana (did you try to do it by your datasource means?), but you may play with JavaScript and external services to achieve that.
Change disable_sanitize_html to true in grafana.ini:
disable_sanitize_html = true

Now you can use JavaScript in Text panel (sample external service ip-api.com is used in this example, domain name is specified by dashboard variable ${domain}):

<p id="ipAddress"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">function cb (x){ document.getElementById('ipAddress').innerHTML=x.query }</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ip-api.com/json/${domain}?callback=cb'></script>

Result:



Thanks, it's working. Just, for others like me, I have a reverse proxy made by apache, and it's blocking queries. (when using "ip:3000" it works fine, but when using my dns that is managed by apache, it's not working fine)
